WebGi and GSAP animation on window load
I have the following WebGiViewer component that I put together from some tutorials and the WebGi docs:
const WebGiViewer = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  const memoizedLoadAnimation = useCallback((position, onUpdate) => {
    if (position && onUpdate) {
      loadAnimation(position, onUpdate);
    }
  });

  const setupViewer = useCallback(async () => {
    // Initialize the viewer
    const viewer = new ViewerApp({
      canvas: canvasRef.current,
    });

    const manager = await viewer.addPlugin(AssetManagerPlugin);

    const camera = viewer.scene.activeCamera;
    const position = camera.position;
    const target = camera.target;

    // Add plugins individually.
    await viewer.addPlugin(GBufferPlugin);
    await viewer.addPlugin(new ProgressivePlugin(32));
    await viewer.addPlugin(new TonemapPlugin(true));
    await viewer.addPlugin(GammaCorrectionPlugin);
    await viewer.addPlugin(SSRPlugin);
    await viewer.addPlugin(SSAOPlugin);
    await viewer.addPlugin(BloomPlugin);

    // Import and add a GLB file.
    viewer.renderer.refreshPipeline();

    await manager.addFromPath("scene.glb");

    viewer.getPlugin(TonemapPlugin).config.clipBackground = true;

    // disabling camera so model cant be adjusted by users
    viewer.scene.activeCamera.setCameraOptions({ controlsEnabled: false });

    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    let needsUpdate = true;

    const onUpdate = () => {
      needsUpdate = true;
      viewer.setDirty();
    };

    viewer.addEventListener("preFrame", () => {
      if (needsUpdate) {
        camera.positionTargetUpdated(true);
        needsUpdate = false;
      }
    });

    memoizedLoadAnimation(position, target, onUpdate);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setupViewer();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div id="webgi-canvas-container">
      <canvas id="webgi-canvas" ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WebGiViewer;

the loadAnimation function is my attempt to make animations happen on window load:
import gsap from "gsap";

export const loadAnimation = (position, onUpdate) => {
  const tl = gsap.timeline();

  tl.to(
    position,
    {
      x: 0,
      y: 5,
      z: 1.5,
      delay: 2,
    },
    onUpdate
  );
};

It's not working and I'm not sure how to fix but I have an idea as to why it's not working. The viewer is only being initialized once and it's being memoized (by useCallback) so the animation (if it happens) will only ever happen once.
I've tried moving the loadAnimation function outside of the setupViewer function and attaching it to window.onload but obviously I don't have access to the position and onUpdate function which are out of scope.
All I want to do is create an animation for my view that'll happen every time the page loads.

The first useCallback is missing the dependencies array. The rest looks correct.
